# Trying to display Using Sum() with JOIN doesn't provide correct output

Tags: sql, join

I'm trying to create a query that displays a user's Id, the sum of total steps, and sum of total calories burnt.

The data for *steps* and *calories* are within two datasets, so I used `JOIN`. However, when I write out the query, the joined data does not look correct. However when I do them separately, it appears to show the correct data

Below are my queries...I am fairly new to SQL, so I am somewhat confused on what I did wrong. How do I correct this? Thank you in advanced for the help!

For the *Steps* table, "Id" and "StepTotal" are Integers. For the *Calories* table, "Id" and "Calories" are also Integers.

```
SELECT steps.Id,Sum(StepTotal) AS Total_steps,Sum(cal.Calories) as Total_calories
FROM fitbit.Daily_steps AS steps
JOIN fitbit.Daily_calories AS cal ON steps.Id=cal.Id
GROUP BY Id
```

[Given Output(Picture)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3mjB8.jpg)

[Expected Output(Picture)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1wu71.jpg)

**For Steps**

```
SELECT Id,Sum(StepTotal) AS Total_steps
FROM fitbit.Daily_steps
group by Id
```

| Id | Total_steps |
| --- | --- |
| 1503960366 | 375619 |
| 1624580081 | 178061 |
| 1644430081 | 218489 |

**For Calories**

```
SELECT Id,Sum(Calories) AS Total_calories
 FROM fitbit.Daily_calories
group by Id
```

| Id | Total_calories |
| --- | --- |
| 1503960366 | 56309 |
| 1624580081 | 45984 |
| 1644430081 | 84339 |

Comment: Can you post the schema of both tables?

Comment: My first thought is to use subqueries so the totals are calculated pre-join. Something like:  `SELECT step.id, step.step_total, cal.cal_total from (SELECT Id,Sum(StepTotal) AS step_total FROM fitbit.Daily_steps group by Id) AS step JOIN (SELECT Id, Sum(Calories) AS cal_total
 FROM fitbit.Daily_calories
group by Id) as cal ON cal.id = step.id`. There may be a better solution, though.

Comment: Hey Reed, that worked though! Thank you so much! I'm still learning how to do subqueries properly, so I did not even think about that. Much appreciated!

Comment: @mlooch97 glad that worked! I posted an answer that explains why your original solution wasn't working & why subqueries fix the problem. I was confused at first myself & had to think about it a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your current solution is returning additional rows as the result of the JOIN.

Let's look at an example data set

```
Steps
id   | total
a    |   5
a    |   7
b    |   3

Calories
id   | total
a    |   100
a    |   300
b    |   400
```

Now, if we `SELECT * FROM Calories`, we'd get 3 rows. If we `SELECT * FROM Calories GROUP BY id`, we'd get two rows.

But if we use a JOIN:

```sql
SELECT Steps.id, Steps.total AS steps, Calories.total AS cals FROM Steps
JOIN Calories
   ON Steps.id = Calories.id
WHERE id = 'a'
```

This would return the following:

```
Steps_Calories
id | steps | cals
a  |   5   | 100
a  |   5   | 300
a  |   7   | 100
a  |   7   | 300
```

So now if we `GROUP BY` & `SUM(steps)`, we get 24, instead of the expected 12, because the `JOIN` returns each pairing of steps & calories.

To mitigate this, we can use sub-queries & group & sum within the sub-queries

```sql
SELECT Steps.id, Steps.total AS steps, Calories.total AS cals 
    FROM (SELECT id, SUM(total) FROM Steps GROUP BY id) as step_totals
    JOIN (Select id, SUM(total) FROM Cals GROUP BY id) as cal_totals
    JOIN Calories
        ON cal_totals.id = step_totals.id
```

Now each subquery only returns a single row for each id, so the join only returns a single row as well.

Of course, you'll have to adapt this for your schema.

Comment: Thank you Reed for the thorough explanation and solution! Honestly, I did not even think about duplicate rows. Much appreciated!